# Long Running Azure Function returns 502, But the function is actually did the work

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-data-factory

I have a Azure Function which copies the data from MongoDB to Azure SQL  DB. When I invoke the Azure function from Azure Data Factory it keep on running. So I tried it form the Postman and it gives the below result after 8 minutes. But actually all the data are copied and if I check the application insight of the Azure Function it completed successfully. Why the Data Factory shows me that the Azure Function is keep on running even though it completed the execution successfully? how to avoid this?

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1- 
strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1"/>
    <title>502 - Web server received an invalid response while acting as a gateway or proxy server.</title>
    <style type="text/css">
        <!--
 body{margin:0;font-size:.7em;font-family:Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;background:#EEEEEE;}
 fieldset{padding:0 15px 10px 15px;} 
h1{font-size:2.4em;margin:0;color:#FFF;}
h2{font-size:1.7em;margin:0;color:#CC0000;} 
h3{font-size:1.2em;margin:10px 0 0 0;color:#000000;} 
#header{width:96%;margin:0 0 0 0;padding:6px 2% 6px 2%;font-family:"trebuchet MS", Verdana, sans-serif;color:#FFF;
background-color:#555555;}
#content{margin:0 0 0 2%;position:relative;}
.content-container{background:#FFF;width:96%;margin-top:8px;padding:10px;position:relative;}
-->

    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="header">
        <h1>Server Error</h1>
    </div>
    <div id="content">
        <div class="content-container">
            <fieldset>
                <h2>502 - Web server received an invalid response while acting as a gateway or proxy server.</h2>
                <h3>There is a problem with the page you are looking for, and it cannot be displayed. When the Web server (while acting as a gateway or proxy) contacted the upstream content server, it received an invalid response from the content server.</h3>
            </fieldset>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Thanks,

Joe

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should be your answer: https://learn.microsoft.com/en/azure/data-factory/control-flow-azure-function-activity#timeout-and-long-running-functions

> Azure Functions times out after 230 seconds regardless of the
>   functionTimeout setting you've configured in the settings. For more
>   information, see this article. To work around this behavior, follow an
>   async pattern or use Durable Functions. The benefit of Durable
>   Functions is that they offer their own state-tracking mechanism, so
>   you won't have to implement your own.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. But I didn't get any timeout error on the Azure Data Factory. Also the timeout should happen at 3 minutes(230 seconds). But this happens only after 8 minutes only

Comment: maybe ADF just gives up to check on the Function response after the 230 seconds? Anyway, the article clearly says that your Function should not take longer, so I'd suggest you change your logic

Comment: @JoeSamraj Hi, Joe. If silent's answer helps you, please mark his answer as the answer of this question. This will help others who meet the similar question.

Comment: @JoeSamraj it can happen that you get a BadGateway response for an actual timeout. This looks strange and inconsistent but looks like it is a case. In this article, you can find the problem statement and solution http://datanrg.blogspot.com/2020/04/using-azure-functions-in-azure-data.html